# Slider banner image is resize to smaller size in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, banner-slider

I am new to magento so I couldn't find the solutions to my problem.

Everything was working fine after I created a CMS page and the slider banner showing image small. I try to flush the cache, delete session files and even started MYSql & Apache2 server, nothing fixed the issues. Also I deleted the files but nothing changes the slider banner.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the url to check ?

Comment: @Prince everything was working fine but I don't know what went wrong and the slider banner is showing like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `skin/frontend/base/default/apt/testimonial/css/testimonial.css line 105`, remove the `width: 186px !important;`

It's better to do it in your css of your current theme.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! for saving my day. Any tips or suggestion how you find the error? Also any tips how I can look for errors in the magento website.

Comment: You're welcome, i inspected your code with a browser console